# SceneKit Textures

Tags: ios, 3d, scenekit

I'm trying to learn SceneKit for iOS and get beyond basic shapes. I'm a little confused on how textures work. In the example project, the plane is a mesh and a flat png texture is applied to it. How do you "tell" the texture how to wrap to the object? In 3D graphics you UV unwrap, but I don't know how I would do this in SceneKit.

Comment: I’m using the Stack Overflow app and don’t see a comment button... so I’m sorry this is appearing as an answer. I’m also new to Stack, Coding, and Blender. How do you export the material in Blender as a PNG?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SceneKit` doesn't have capabilities to create a mesh (other than programatically creating vertex positions, normals, UVs etc). What you'd need to do is create your mesh and texture in another bit of software (I use Blender). Then export the mesh as a collada `.dae` file and export the textures your model uses too as `.png` files. Your exported model will have UV coordinates imported with it that will correctly wrap your imported textures on your model.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know .dae's included UV.

Comment: great answer! I'm using blender too. It was the only way i could wrap my head around this problem. And it works beautifully

Comment: I’ll chime-in on Blender as well. It’s a great app! But, if you’re not familiar with modeling apps, it can be a bit overwhelming. Fortunately, there are plenty of places to find the answer to any question you might have.